# Can I use android Tap-to-Pay in my own application?

Tags: android, google-pay, android-tap-and-pay

I have a hobby project similar to a budgeting app.  Ideally, I want the app to prevent me from making purchases I can't afford by monitoring contactless transactions.

This could either be a plugin to google pay (if that possibility exists?) or an app that delegates the payment to Google Pay after validating the inputs (eg, the amount being purchased, time/location etc)

I built a mock-up using Host-based card emulation on Android, but the experience was painful.  This question: [Payment through HCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70394836/payment-through-hce) implies I could use Google Pay or something similar.

So far everything I've come across deals with requesting payments from the user, to be clear - that's not what this is about.  I want the user to use their own card to buy stuff unrelated to me, and the app just permits/denys the purchase.

Comment: Hey, did you end up finding a solution to this? I had a similar idea but this is currently a blocker

Comment: No, I never did.  It's a pity, because there seems to be a lot of opportunity for innovation there (that doesn't run through a VC with banking connections)

Comment: I did get a version of HCE passthrough to my physical card, sitting on my desk on a NFC reader, but it was never reliable enough that I felt comfortable leaving my card at home :-D

Comment: Ah it really is a pity. Thank you anyway <3